# How to do Simple CSV Export functioin with jQuery datatable & PHP

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I want to export the visible data in datatable to CSV format. Here is my code,I have added following code

```
var $table=$('#example').dataTable
                ( {
                    "bFilter": false,           
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,

                      "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                      "oTableTools": {
                             "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                                },

                    "ajax": {
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': 'getResult.php',
                        'data': {
                                    formName:'afscpMcn',
                                    action:'search',
                                    mcn_no: document.getElementById('mcn_no').value,
                                    cust_nm:document.getElementById('cust_name').value,
                                    emp_id: document.getElementById('employ_name').value
                                }
                            }

                 });
```

Comment: Where's the code that does the CSV export?

Comment: I dont know, In datatable website they only mentioned this code,I am not getting how to use click button and ajax call for export functionality.   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
 "oTableTools": {
 "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
  }

Comment: Where exactly do they mention that?

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/buttons

Comment: why negative vote for this??  I am asking correct question only right?.

Comment: I would suspect that the down-votes are because your question didn't provide any information about your attempt at CSV export functionality.  Until you clarified in comments that you were trying to use the TableTools extension of DataTables, it looked like you just made a button and wanted us to write the actual CSV export functionality for you.  I recommend updating the question to include relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables has no native functionality for saving data to CSV.  The page you're looking at is for an extension called [TableTools](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/).  That extension uses a SWF file to perform its functionality:

```
"tableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
}
```

which is missing from your code.

Comment: I have added above code,  and create the folder called swf, but no change in result

Comment: @chaya: Did you include the SWF file in the folder?  Is the browser successfully requesting that file?

Comment: I have included that files

Comment: @chaya: And is the browser successfully requesting that file?  I'm not in control of your computer, I can't debug your application for you.

Comment: Hi david, Now it is working fine..But I dont want to export the last column of datatable..

Comment: @chaya: And what have you tried?  Seems like TableTools makes that pretty straightforward: https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options

Comment: I have added the following code:
                "tableTools": 
                 {
                   "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
               },
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
               "oTableTools": {
                            "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls" ]
                               },

Comment: @chaya: You should really at least *look* at the options for TableTools.  Specifically the one called `mColumns` in this case.  Stack Overflow isn't a very good replacement for a product's documentation.